# How can I translate the name of my Plugin for other languages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, localization, textdomain

How can I translate the name of plugin for other languages? For example:

When Wordpress is in pt-BR language, the plugin would be "Meu plugin".

If the Wordpress is in en-XX language, the plugin name would be "My plugin".

Thanks!

Comment: Did you had a look at the official WP docs? https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/

Comment: Yes, @FabianMarz, in the docs is not clear how to translate Plugin Header fields Like plugin name and Description for example. It is automatic?

Comment: @FabianMarz this is for the header comment, rather than strings in PHP

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little bit more, I found that in the generation of the .pot file, the strings of plugin header already appear there. The tool I used to generate .pot file for my plugin was this command of `wp-cli`: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/

I don't know if another tools to make plugin translation do that. The reason to use `wp-cli` instead of POEdit looks like .pot file generation is a premium feature of this kind of software ( version 1.6.11 tested in Windows 10).

So, basically with the .pot file (my-plugin-textdomain.pot) of your plugin and the translation of that (my-plugin-textdomain-language.po and my-plugin-textdomain-language.mo). You should load that using in your plugin file:

```php
function my_plugin_init(){
   load_plugin_textdomain('my-plugin-text-domain', false, 'my-plugin-folder/languages');
}

add_action('init', 'my_plugin_init');
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/